# Change DATE_ADD's unit based on column's value

Tags: mysql

I have a table which stores the `datetime` an operation was `last_run`, I also have a `frequency` column, which is the frequency, in months, that the operation should run.

```
+----+---------------------+-----------+
| id | last_run            | frequency |
+----+---------------------+-----------+
| 1  | 2014-05-22 00:00:00 |    12     |
|----|---------------------|-----------|
| 2  | 2015-05-15 00:00:00 |   0.25    |
+----+---------------------+-----------+
```

I'm using the following query to obtain the date that the operation should next be run:

`SELECT DATE_ADD(last_run, INTERVAL frequency MONTH) AS next_run FROM table;`

This fails to return the correct `next_run` date on the second record because of the `frequency` value.

Is it possible to add a condition so that when `frequency = 0.25`

- `frequency` becomes `7`
- `MONTH` becomes `DAY`

This is part of an old system which I am currently refactoring. Would it just be better to store the interval type (`DAY/MONTH/YEAR`), and pass that to the query, or is there a way of adding the above conditions to the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use a big `case` statement.  Something like this:

```
select (case when frequency >= 1
             then DATE_ADD(last_run, INTERVAL frequency MONTH)
             when frequency < 1
             then DATE_ADD(last_run, INTERVAL frequency*28 DAY)
             ELSE DATE_ADD(last_run, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) --Adding for may be null values
        end)
```